# openCV's gnustl conflict with dlib's c++_shared in the android NDK

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, dlib

I'm trying to integrate both [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/) and [dlib-android](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android) in the NDK.
I'm able to get both OpenCV and dlib working in seperate projects, but the project breaks when they both are integrated.

This is my gradle config for dlib

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
            arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16",
                    "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                    "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
                    "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/jniLibs/dlib/libs"]
        }
    }
}
...
```

When I integrate openCV, I get

> undefined reference to 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

The solution to which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370259/undefined-reference-to-cvcascadeclassifierdetectmultiscale-but-other-lib/37377582#37377582), is to have the stl as `gnustl_shared`

dlib with `gnustl_shared` gives errors like `std::exceptions` not found.

How do I go forward and integrate both?

I tried to recompile OpenCV with `c++_shared` on CMake, but ran into

> fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
>    #include

Comment: You can't mix and match STLs, unfortunately. They aren't ABI compatible. OpenCV has their own CMake toolchain file. It's possible that theirs isn't compatible with libc++?